# STM32 Stop mode

Tags: arm, stm32, iar

I am using STM32G031F6 microcontroller and I set up Stop Mode.
code :

```
  SysTick->CTRL &= ~SysTick_CTRL_TICKINT_Msk;
  
  PWR->CR1 = (PWR->CR1 & ~PWR_CR1_LPMS) | PWR_CR1_LPMS_0;
  SCB->SCR |= (uint32_t)SCB_SCR_SLEEPDEEP_Msk;
  DBG->CR |= DBG_CR_DBG_STOP;
  __WFI();
  
  SCB->SCR &= (uint32_t)~SCB_SCR_SLEEPDEEP_Msk;
  SystemCoreClockUpdate();
  
  SysTick_Config((SystemCoreClock / 1000));
```

The problem I have now is that when I program with st link, it consumes 300uA in stop mode, while it should be 4uA. But when I completely cut off the power and reconnect it, the current consumption is 4uA.
What should I do so that after programming the current will be 4uA and there is no need to cut off the power supply?

Comment: It depend on what peripherals have been configured and used prior the stop mode. Read [AP4899 application note](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/group0/13/c0/f6/6c/29/3b/47/b3/DM00315319/files/DM00315319.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00315319.pdf) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Debugger may enable a bit which [keeps the processor running](http://efton.sk/STM32/gotcha/g117.html) during low-power modes. There may be some setting in your toolchain (IDE) to prevent this.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like it will be solved when the debugger mode is disabled in the IAR's project menu options.